# Загрузка большого количества изображений в фоновом потоке

Tags: изображения, android, потоки-данных, java, android-asynctask

Всем добрый день!
Понимаю, скажете вопрос повторяю и всех уже порядком достал, но мне необходимо реализовать довольно быструю загрузку большого кол-ва изображений на память андроид устройства!
Так вот `Universal Image Loader` работает довольно медленно и некоторые его возможности мне совершенно не нужны.

Так вот порыскав в интернете нашел код работающего приложения которое загружает изображение из сети в фоновом потоке на SD карту. Немного подправил его и вроде работает, но теперь мне необходимо загрузить массив ссылок в фоновом потоке причем на внутреннюю память устройства.

Ниже код:

```
public class image extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "PRANJAL";
private boolean isImage = false;
private String reviewImageLink;
private ProgressDialog pd;
String k = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_BFp02Fm5oSs/TQecAHhepFI/AAAAAAAAAEY/Yyo8h2oQB0w/s1600/Download%2BImage.PNG";
String urls[] = {k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,k,};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
reviewImageLink = urls[1];
URL reviewImageURL;
String name = "myImage";
try {
    reviewImageURL = new URL(urls[1]);
    if (!hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(name)) {
        isImage = false;
        new DownloadImageTask().execute(reviewImageURL);
        Log.v("log_tag", "if");
        isImage = true;
        File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources()
                .getString(R.string.directory));
        sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, name);
        Log.v("log_tag", "Directory created");
    }

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    Log.v(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

}

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(URL... paths) {
        URL url;
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i<paths.length; i++) {
            url = paths[i];
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            int length = connection.getContentLength();
            InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
            byte[] imageData = new byte[length];
            int buffersize = (int) Math.ceil(length / (double) 100);
            int downloaded = 0;
            int read;
            while (downloaded < length) {
                if (length < buffersize) {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length);
                } else if ((length - downloaded) <= buffersize) {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length
                            - downloaded);
                } else {
                    read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, buffersize);
                }
                downloaded += read;
                publishProgress((downloaded * 100) / length);
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                    length);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap created");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap not created");
            }
            is.close();
            return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Malformed exception: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(image.this);
            pd.setMessage("Загружаюсь...");
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.setCancelable(true);
            pd.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        String name = "myImage";
        if (result != null) {
            hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(name);
            saveToSDCard(result, name);
            isImage = true;

        } else {
            isImage = false;

        }
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}

public void saveToSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
        Log.v(TAG, "SD Card is available for read and write "
                + mExternalStorageAvailable + mExternalStorageWriteable);
        saveFile(bitmap, name);
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
        mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        Log.v(TAG, "SD Card is available for read "
                + mExternalStorageAvailable);
    } else {
        mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
        Log.v(TAG, "Please insert a SD Card to save your Video "
                + mExternalStorageAvailable + mExternalStorageWriteable);
    }
}

private void saveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
    String filename = name;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources().getString(
            R.string.directory));
    sdImageMainDirectory.mkdirs();
    File outputFile = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, outputFile.toString());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, System
            .currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
    Uri uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,

            values);
    try {
        OutputStream outStream = this.getContentResolver()
                .openOutputStream(uri);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, outStream);

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean hasExternalStoragePublicPicture(String name) {
    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources().getString(
            R.string.directory));
    File file = new File(sdImageMainDirectory, name);
    if (file != null) {
        file.delete();
    }
    return file.exists();
}
```

}

Помогите разобраться!

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Неужели ни у кого нет вариантов как это сделать?

Comment: Минусовать конечно прикольно, но может кто нить даст ответ! Или объяснит почему минусует!

Comment: Потому что [SSCCE][1]. Вот эту простыню кода никто читать не будет.

  [1]: http://sscce.org

Comment: @Flamьable я задавал довольно короткие и информативные вопросы на эту тему, но в ответ получал - "так это же просто!". Я вот по образованию конструктор ракетных двигателей, и есть вещи которые для меня очень просты, а сообществом программистов на данном форуме просто не постижимы. Так вот если я получаю такие ответы, они не дают мне ни практического решения, ни направления для размышлений, а просто расстройство!

Comment: @vanyamelikov: но ведь и правда: для того, чтобы разобраться, где ошибка в простыне кода, надо скомпилировать её, запустить в отладчике, понять, как должны работать функции по замыслу автора, под отладчиком обнаружить первую точку, которая не работает. Участникам сайта это сделать лень. Вот если бы вы сами потратили время и нашли ту строчку, в которой значения переменных не такие, как вы ожидаете, и выкинули весь остальной код, то либо вам бы самому стало очевидно, в чём проблема, либо код стал бы маленьким, и кто-то бы тут же ответил. А так тупиковая ситуация.

Comment: @vanyamelikov: Если проблема в скорости, опять же: попробуйте отпрофилировать каждую функцию (посчитать время выполнения). Найдите медленную функцию, определите, какой кусок этой функции тормозит.

Comment: Загвоздка не в ошибке работы кода! Он работает прекрасно при скачивании одного изображения, а вот массив как скачать? Вот это как раз и не выходит! Я опять же говорю, я вопрос на эту тему уже задавал в довольно коротком виде, но ответов не получал, поэтому и прибежал скодом, чтобы не говорили погугли и все найдешь! Неужели Вы думаете, что сидя над этой проблемой в 3:38 ночи я ленюсь погуглить?

Comment: @vanyamelikov: А в чём проблема с массивом? Скачали первый файл, скачали второй, скачали третий, и так до конца массива. Если вы не пользуетесь глобальными переменными и тому подобным, это можно даже сделать параллельно: пока один файл сохраняется, грузить остальные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ой, я не знаю в чем проблема, вы слишком мудрено все написали.  Мне лень было разбираться, я написал с нуля. Вот [проект](https://github.com/rovkinmax/DownloadArrayImage) на github.

Comment: @Andreich приблизительно такого рода код я и писал в первом приближении, но возникает проблема, что на эмуляторе все прогружается, а на девайсе некоторые файлы грузяться не до конца. У меня сложилось ощушение, будто буфер не сбрасывается. Ставил закрытие потоков, но все равно не все картинки до конца не загружаются! Как думаете в чем может быть причина?

Comment: не имею понятия, я на эмуляторе в принципе не запускаю :)
только девайсы

Comment: Ок спасибо! Буду разбираться! А как лучше реализовать проверку на наличие такого изображения, и при условии что оно есть не перезаписывать его?

Comment: у класса File есть метод exists

Comment: @Andreich возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при скачивании файла он проводил компрессию одного файла в два. Первого в 30% от исходного размера, а второго в 70%?

Comment: а не проще ли сделать сразу необходимые файлы на сервере, лучше один раз нарисовать и все, к тому же будет меньш трафика расходоваться